# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

Calling `IO3D.services` results in:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

version:
https://3d.io 1.0.0-beta.22 (@master #274adf0 2017/08/02 10:16)

What i tried:

```
IO3D.services.call('Model.search', {
    arguments: {
        organizationResourceId: <my_organisationResourceId>,
        folderResourceName: '<my_folder_name>',
    },
}).then(console.log)
```

So is the services-api not available yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to call APIs directly use:

```
IO3D.utils.services.call( )
```

sample on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0f6n8wp0/

services.call function in the library:
https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js/blob/master/src/utils.js#L24

Answer (score 1):

So far it is available as an experimental feature only:

```
IO3D.utils.services.call('Model.search', {
  arguments: {
    organizationResourceName: 'template',
    folderResourceName: 'default',
  },
}).then(console.log)
```

JsFddile: https://jsfiddle.net/3dio/ykut9gx1/

Once out of experimental stage it we available in it's own namespace as something like `IO3D.scene.search(…)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly.
Tried to also use `organizationResourceId`instead of `organizationResourceName`.
Is this also panned?

Comment: Good point! Using permanent IDs as params would be certainly more solid than using changeable names. We will consider that in our API design.